# Best way to redirect pages with htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I about to merge two website domains.  For argument sake lets say the boo.com is migrating to foo.com.  I know redirecting boo to foo is a must.  But boo.com has some well ranked pages that take a lot of traffic & would like to send that traffic to somewhere other than the foo.com homepage.  My question is...is it possible to setup redirects for specific pages & then redirect the delta new domain homepage via htaccess?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: What is a "delta new domain homepage"?

Comment: Hey there, can you please give us some feedback on the work we did (did the solutions work, do you need tweaks etc)? If something worked, please click the checkmark to the left. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! It's possible.

All you have to do is place the special redirects before the global redirect. For instance:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect special pages
RewriteRule ^my_special_page_1 http://foo.com/special_1.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^my_special_page_2 http://bar.com/special_2.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^my_special_page_3 http://baz.com/special_3.html [L,R=301]

# Catch all the others
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  i thought htaccess was serial in that it would execute the special redirects first & if one of the special conditions wasn't hit, then it could execute a domain level redirect.  thanks for the confirmation.